# how decrease UDP backlog to once packet at a time?

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, udp, sysctl, backlog

Most articles are about how to increase a UDP socket's receive buffer size to handle more packets, but I need a solution to decrease the UDP receive buffer to accept only 1 packet at a time and discard/drop all other packets until that packet is read.

I'm trying to do this for Linux, and did some network stack tuning, like setting the `RCVBUFF` and `RCVBUFFFORCE` socket options, but that didn't work.  I cannot reduce `RCVBUFF` lower than 2046B (maybe 1 memory page), even when setting the `udp_rmem_min` to 0.

Why i can’t set UDP RCVBUF lower than 2046?

Comment: You can probably do this with tc.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html

Comment: when my code is processing, linux stack receives many packets and queue them but i want to receive no packet when my code is processing

Comment: @stark I need it done programmatically and effectively

Comment: @abgr AFAIK, there is no socket option for what you are attempting.  Why can't you simply read and discard the packets you don't want? I would move the reading into a separate thread, and simply have it discard any packet the main processing thread is not ready to handle.

Comment: it’s a special case i need to this;

Comment: Is this "one packet at a time total" or "one packet at a time from each source-IP-address-and-port" ?

Comment: each packet at a time total and don’t queue any other packet and drop others until last packet dequeue